# Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions with nib file

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, cocos2d-iphone, transition

In my project, I use cocos2D. My problem is, that sometimes I get the error message "Unbalanced calls to begin appearance transitions for < aViewController >... The view controller wich cause the trouble is in a framework, it is a nib file, so I can't see anything of this view controller and how it is use in the framework.
I saw onto the internet that this error is caused when two view controllers are launched at the same time, and this is, I think, my case. In fact when I have this warning when I quit a scene, and from the other menu relaunch the scene. I get a blackscreen but I heard the music of the scene, and when I try to print the opacity of a sprite, it always gives me 255.
I read that, replace scene method remove the precedent scene and push the new one, so I would have only one scene on the screen, but in fact it looks like not...
I tried to add (when I quit the scene, in order to put the view at the back if it is here...) :

```
[self setZOrder:-100];
[self setVisible:NO];
[self removeFromParentAndCleanup:YES];
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[CCTransitionFade transitionWithDuration:0.1 scene:[Menu scene]]];
```

But bothing looks like working. I can't get access to the view controller which cause the unbalanced transition because it is a nib file in the framework, and can't remove properly the black screen which is an old screen...

How could I solve this problem ?

Thank you for your help !

Comment: would you mind mentioning what that framework is?

Comment: It is a framework from an unknown company... Have you some ideas from where it could come from ? I really don't know how to fix it...

Comment: you are using a framework you don't even know where it's from, did i get this right? Are you sure you can legally use the framework in the first place? Did you check for updates or any alternatives?

Comment: I know where it comes from, and I could legally use it, i work with them. I check the updates, but don't you think this blackscreen could come from another matter ? Is there a code line to close all the views even the visible one ? (Even if I thought that replace scene do this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing I'd try is

```
po [[UIWindow keyWindow] recursiveDescription]
```

then you can see what the layering of views is, and relevant properties.

Another approach is to ask for sample projects if any exist that accompany the framework to show how to use it.  Often, the runtime character and usage of an API is under-documented, with the main focus being just the method calls.  Code examples can shed a light in this area.

You say you're using cocos 2d; are you using any custom drawers?  Are you implementing all the callbacks you are supposed to?

Comment: Thank you for this great tip ! I think I have correctly implementing all callbacks, my matter only appears when i go to background, relaunch, close the view, relaunch, and go to background. (--> My matter is in direct link with background mode)